# How to setup a Remote Desktop access to the Windows Home Server box?

Tags: windows-home-server

I have Acer easyStore H340, which does not allow full Remote Desktop access out-of-box (only WHS console). Anybody knows the recipe for enabling it? Remote access is the **only way** to get to the server since it does not have keyboard and video terminals.

EDIT:
In fact, the remote access is there, it was just hard to find - and until you found it, it is impossible to configure anything that is not configurable through console.

EDIT:
When I tried to connect the first time using Remote Desktop Connection, I probably messed up the login info. Later, when I used right-click from the Network\MYSERVER  in Explorer, the RDC put in correct logon attributes (MYSERVER\Administrator) and I was able to go in. The fact you need to use "Administrator" for WHS remote access using RDC is not covered anywhere in the doc.

Comment: Under `Start -> Run -> sysdm.cpl -> Remote -> Remote Desktop`, is `Allow users to connect...` checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>Pause / Break</kbd>, then on the right had side click "Remote Settings", Next, make sure you have enabled and allowed Remote Desktop, and enabled the users you want to connect with.

You should now be able to connect.

Comment: When enabled, I think Administrators have access by default.

Comment: +1 Correct, the current user who made the change and anyone in the Administrators group have access by default

Answer (score 1):

This is where I found how to connect: in Explorer, expand Network node, right-click your home server, select "Connect with Remote Desktop Connection". You'll be connected with "Administrator" login and your WHS password in full mode.

Comment: You were just looking for `mstsc`, eh?  Anyway, Wil correctly answered the question as it was written, please consider accepting his answer.

Comment: I tried Remote Desktop Connection (mstsc) before asking the question, but somehow login did not work the first time. Maybe I put in an incorrect user name.